# fullcalendar scheduler vertical-resource-view

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler

In the example [vertical-resource-view](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.4.0/demos/vertical-resource-view.html), there are 4 rooms (resources) shown (A,B,C,D) - which scale down onto a responsive mobile device ok.

My question is, what happens if there were 5+ rooms/resources - when you try to scale these down on a mobile device too small to display all horizontally - do they switch to a stacked display?

Many thanks

Regards

Jamie

Comment: As the number of resources grows the width of the columns shrink. You can resize them and add a scroll but it isn't the nicest thing to use if you have too many resources

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Daffy, very useful to know and much appreciated.